# When I try to do a newline, it doesn't insert properly

Tags: c, terminal, printf

When running my program, when I try to input a newline by doing `printf("\n")`, it doesn't work properly and just adds a ton of spaces

My compiler code:

`gcc code.c -o code`

the compiler outputs nothing (it's sucessful).

Running:

`./code`

My code (code.c) [EDIT: I have updated the code to reflect suggestions/answers others have given me]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kbhit.h"
#include "kbhit.c"

char def_map[137] = "\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
# # # # # # # #\r\n\
\n";

char map[137];

int pos[2] = {0,0};

void reset_map() {for (int i=0;i<137;i++) {map[i] = def_map[i];};};

int update(){
    reset_map();

    map[pos[0]*2+pos[1]*17] = '@';

    printf("%s\r\n",map);

    return 0;
}

int move(char dir){
    if (dir == 'u') {
        pos[1] -= 1;
    } else if (dir == 'd') {
        pos[1] += 1;
    } else if (dir == 'l') {
        pos[0] -= 1;
    } else if (dir == 'r') {
        pos[0] += 1;
    };

    printf("%d,%d\r\n",pos[0],pos[1]);
    update();
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    reset_map();

    /*printf("\nHi there! I'd like to know your name. Actually, you COULD do something like Minecraft or TESTER or something like that. But not more than 50 characters. That's too much. I tried it, and I got:\n\n\
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated\n\
Aborted (core dumped)\n\n\
Name: ");
    char a[50];
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("Hi, %s! This is all meaningless, so you won't see much\n",a);*/

    printf("%s\r\n",map);

    while (1) {
        while(!kbhit()){};

        int c = fgetc(stdin);

        if (c == 'q') {break;};

        switch (c) {
            case 'w':
                move('u');
                break;
            case 'a':
                move('l');
                break;
            case 's':
                move('d');
                break;
            case 'd':
                move('r');
                break;
        }
    };

    printf("\r\n");
    close_keyboard();
    return 0;
}
```

kbhit:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "kbhit.h"
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>   // for read()

static struct termios initial_settings, new_settings;
static int peek_character = -1;

void init_keyboard()
{
    tcgetattr(0,&initial_settings);
    new_settings = initial_settings;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    new_settings.c_lflag &= ~ISIG;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
}

void close_keyboard()
{
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &initial_settings);
}

int kbhit()
{
unsigned char ch;
int nread;

    if (peek_character != -1) return 1;
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=0;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    nread = read(0,&ch,1);
    new_settings.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
    tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &new_settings);
    if(nread == 1)
    {
        peek_character = ch;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int readch()
{
char ch;

    if(peek_character != -1)
    {
        ch = peek_character;
        peek_character = -1;
        return ch;
    }
    read(0,&ch,1);
    return ch;
}
```

Output:

```
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #
# # # # # # # #


[w key twice]0,1
   # # # # # # # #
                  @ # # # # # # #
                                 # # # # # # # #
                                                # # # # # # # #
                                                               # # # # # # # #
                                                                              # # # # # # # #
          # # # # # # # #
                         # # # # # # # #


                                        [q]user@localhost:/path/to/dir$ [return]user@localhost:/path/to/dir$ [return]user@localhost:/path/to/dir$
```

I tried using terminator instead of gnome-terminal and the same problem occurred

Comment: Looks like you might be on Windows and need `\r\n` instead of just `\n`.

Comment: No, I'm on Linux. I'll try \r\n though

Comment: That fixed the problem. Now I'll update the title. This is probably the wrong place to post this, anyway.

Comment: same problem still occurs in the terminal though. I can use `reset` to fix that though.

Comment: regarding the instances of `};`  That is actually invalid syntax in almost all cases.   The compiler outputs: *untitled1.c:20:67: warning: ISO C does not allow extra ‘;’ outside of a function [-Wpedantic]*

Comment: OT:  regarding: `char c = fgetc(stdin);`  The function: `fgetc()` returns an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: regarding: `
char def_map[137] = "\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
\n";

char map[137];`   That table is only 127 bytes, including the final '\n'.  In general, it is much better to let the compiler calculate sizes, Similar to: `
char def_map[] = "\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
# # # # # # # #\n\
\n";

char map[ sizeof( def_map ) ];

Comment: It used to have ' \n' at the end. I added the '\r\n' that kichik suggested so it's still [137]

Comment: Ah. I'll change that (the char thing) too. I'm a bit new to C, so I'm not the best at it. And the compiler outputs no warnings or errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show the code for kbhit, but its most likely the problem is coming from there -- it's likely putting the terminal into some nonstandard mode (perhaps ~ONLCR) and not restoring it.

Check that any code that changes the terminal mode with `tcgetattr`/`tcsetattr` saves the original mode and restores it after it is done...

---

The problem is that you never call `init_keyboard`, so `new_settings` is never initialized with the current terminal settings -- which means that when you call `kbhit` it corrupts the output settings.  In addition, you should be calling the `readch` function to read a keypress instead of `fgetc`.

You need to call `init_keyboard` before ever calling `kbhit` or `readch`, and call `close_keyboard` aftwards before calling any stdio function that reads from stdin.  Between the `init_keyboard` and `close_keyboard` you should use *only* `kbhit` and `readch` to read input and never use stdio functions on stdin.

Comment: Found it! I just need to run close_keyboard(); at the end

Comment: I tried putting close_keyboard(); at the end (it should reset the terminal mode) but it didn't work. I'll put the kbhit code in my question